# Docker mysql failing to run when mounting volume

Tags: mysql, docker

Trying to run mysql docker image with data for my db stored in a folder:

```
mkdir myfolder
sudo docker run --privileged --name my_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 -v "$PWD/myfolder":/var/lib/mysql -d mysql
```

Container justs dies and logs yield these info:

```
sudo docker logs --tail=50 abcdef
Initializing database
mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)
2019-03-10T10:03:42.872059Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-03-10T10:03:42.872191Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) initializing of server in progress as process 30
2019-03-10T10:03:42.875755Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] Newly created data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can safely remove it.
2019-03-10T10:03:42.875824Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-03-10T10:03:42.876931Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

What is going on? I've done this type of things before with other DB without issues.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems to be some specific bug. What OS and Docker version are you using? Can you also use an image with a specific tag? E.g. `:8`

Comment: Docker version 17.05.0-ce run on a linux machine

Comment: run `docker pull mysql` to update the image then try again, if there are no containers using mysql image then remove it first by running `dokcer rmi mysql`

Comment: Well.. looks like the issue is with this https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69 this is a know issue.
The cumbersome solution is:

1. Run `sudo docker run --privileged --name my_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 -d mysql`
2. Move the `_data` folder in the `volumes/volumeid/` folder created to your local dir (in my case renaming it `myfolder`)
3. Run `sudo docker run --privileged --name my_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 -v "$PWD/myfolder":/var/lib/mysql -d mysql`

:-/